# How to reset autoincrement id of all tables in a database using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use the command

```
DBCC checkident ('tablename', reseed, 200000000);
```

but I have over 150 tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use undocumented feature `sp_MSforeachtable` http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'DBCC checkident ([?], reseed, 200000000)';
```